# Como consultar e retornar todas as informações referente a um produto?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho o seguinte problema e vou fazer uma pergunta de forma didática para que possa ser útil à todos os usuários que possam precisar. Quero realizar uma consulta ***SQL*** que responda a todos os requisitos e retorne os valores.

A `tbl_cor` neste caso é para registrar o produto com todas as suas possibilidades de cores. Isso será feito em um outro formulário aonde um drop retornará todos os produtos para a escolha de um deles e posterior cadastro das possíveis cores.

```
tbl_produto
    id_prod
    nome_prod
    preco_prod
    cat_prod      <----- id da categoria
    datacad_prod

tbl_categoria
    id_cat
    nome_cat      

tbl_cor
    id_prod
    cor_prod      <----- string de um dropdown do form
```

> **Exemplo:**

O `produto` é ***Kombe*** da `categoria` ***veículo utilitário*** disponível nas `cores` ***verde, azul, branco, amarela***. Como retornar através de uma consulta ***SQL*** estes dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode utilizar a função *GROUP_CONCAT* para retornar mais de um registro em uma única coluna. Como você tem várias cores para um único produto ao invés de retornar uma linha para cada cor, você pode estar retornando somente uma linha com uma coluna contendo todas as cores.

```
SELECT
   tbl_produto.nome_prod,
   tbl_categoria.nome_cat,
   GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_cor.cor_prod) AS Cor
FROM tbl_cor
INNER JOIN tbl_produto ON tbl_produto.id_prod = tbl_cor.id_prod  
INNER JOIN tbl_categoria ON tbl_produto.cat_prod = tbl_categoria.id_cat
WHERE tbl_produto.nome_prod = 'KOMBE'
GROUP BY (tbl_produto.id_prod, tbl_categoria.id_cat)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Neste exemplo nãoo está mostrando a categoria.Como mostrá-la? http://axitech.com.br/veiculo.php

Comment: Fiz a alteração no código para contemplar a categoria. Abração.

Comment: Ai eu explodo os dados retornados e coloco no dropdown como itens do produto, isso?

Answer (score 3):

A seguinte consulta retorna todas as informações do produto, com suas cores e categoria.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_produto AS produtos,
     tbl_categ AS categorias,
     tbl_cor AS cores
WHERE produtos.cat_prod = categorias.id_cat AND
      produtos.id_prod = cores.id_prod
ORDER BY nome_prod;
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, não entendi se você quer apenas uma consulta ou algo mais complicado, fiz essa consulta aqui:

```
SELECT nome_prod, nome_cat, cor_prod
FROM tbl_produto
INNER JOIN tbl_categoria
ON tbl_produto.cat_prod = tbl_categoria.id_cat
INNER JOIN tbl_cor
ON tbl_produto.id_prod = tbl_cor.id_prod
WHERE tbl_produto.nome_prod = 'KOMBE'
```

Espero que ajude, qualquer coisa comente.